# Array in TypeOrm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity with arrays of identifiers in my postgres database, how can I add, remove, update a specific array in my entity, in my service with typeorm?

```
 @Entity('favourites')
    export class FavoritesEntity {
       @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
       id: number;

       @Column('simple-array', { array: true, default: [] })
       artists: string[];

       @Column('simple-array', { array: true, default: [] })
       albums: string[];

       @Column('simple-array', { array: true, default: [] })
       tracks: string[];
    }
```